# Windows TaskScheduler DailyTrigger run for a duration of

Tags: c#, windows-task-scheduler

I'm creating a trigger for a task in Windows using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.DailyTrigger to run daily at 8am. That task repeats every hour but I want it to stop after 10 hours until it fires up again the next day.

In the Windows task scheduler application, under trigger you have something like "Repeat task every 1 hour for a duration of 10 hours".

The repeat task every hour I can do, but I can't find a way to do the "for a duration of". This is the code I have to set up the trigger so far, startTime is a DateTime set to 8am today.

```
var dailyTrigger = new DailyTrigger();
dailyTrigger.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
dailyTrigger.StartBoundary = startTime;
dailyTrigger.ExecutionTimeLimit = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(59);
```

I could do it with multiple triggers, but I was thinking if the application interface allows it there probably is a way to do it in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I noticed below is a different class, and the OP probably downloaded [a library from Codeplex](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TriggerSamples&referringTitle=Classes%20Overview). The below still applies, it's just `Repetition.Interval` and `Repetition.Duration`.

```
// Set the time in between each repetition of the task after it starts to 30 minutes.
tt.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60); // Default is TimeSpan.Zero (or never)
// Set the time the task will repeat to 1 day.
tt.Repetition.Duration = TimeSpan.FromDays(1); // Default is TimeSpan.Zero (or never)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.excel.server.addins.computecluster.taskscheduler.trigger.intervalminutes(v=office.12).aspx

> **IntervalMinutes**
>
> Gets or sets the number of minutes between executions for a task that is to run repeatedly.
>
> [...]
>
> The task continues to run repeatedly until the interval specified in
> the DurationMinutes property expires. The IntervalMinutes value is
> counted from the start of the previous execution. The
>
> IntervalMinutes value must be less than the DurationMinutes value.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.excel.server.addins.computecluster.taskscheduler.trigger.durationminutes(v=office.12).aspx

> **DurationMinutes**
>
> Gets or sets the number of minutes that the trigger remains active after the trigger fires.
>
> [...]
>
> This property is used in conjunction with the IntervalMinutes property
> to run a task repeatedly for a period of time. For example, to start a
> task at 8:00 A.M. and repeatedly restart it until 5:00 P.M., the
> DurationMinutes value would be 540 minutes (9 hours).
>
> The DurationMinutes value can also be used to terminate a running task
> after the DurationMinutes property for the task expires.
>
> You use the KillAtDurationEnd property to specify that the task is
> terminated after its DurationMinutes expires. The value of DurationMinutes must be greater than or equal to the IntervalMinutes
> setting.

Comment: Doh! I looked everywhere apart from the most obvious place! Many thanks @peter